# Electron App and HTTPS/SSL authentication with smart-cards pcks11

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, electron, smartcard

I am writing an electron app which sends HTTP requests to a public API (minister of justice) in order to let attorneys view their proceedings and folders. The Minister has exposed a specific proxy which expects a client certificate (contained in a smart card).

This is the actual situation:

**Windows**: no problem. The chromium version of electron reads the certificates from the windows certificate store and displays a popup window in order to authenticate user;
**Mac**: more complex, but working. If the smart-card is visible onto the keychain, The chromium version of electron reads the certificates from the keychain and displays a popup window in order to authenticate user

**Linux/Ubuntu**: **strange situation**. I have followed this guide in order to let chromium aware of the smart card: (https://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Hardware/Periferiche/CartaNazionaleServizi) and, i executed this command to add the library path of smart card to the nssdb:

`modutil -dbdir sql:.pki/nssdb/ -add "OpenSC" -libfile /usr/lib/$(uname -i)-*/opensc-pkcs11.so`

The normal chromium works and i'm able to log in to protected sites asking for smartcard authentication, but the electron chromium cannot work.

The strange thing is that mac os and windows version work regularly but the linux version does not. Anyone has experience with this subject on ubuntu/linux? There is a system certificate store other than the nssdb ?